# Filebeat fields_under_root is not working

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

This is my Apache module setting

```
- module: apache2
  access:
    enabled: false
  error:
    enabled: true
    prospector:
       fields:
          beat.name: xxxx
    fields_under_root: true
```

But since I view the log in the Kibana

```
"fields": {
  "beat": {
    "name": "xxxx"
  }
},
"@version": "1",
"host": "something_else",
"beat": {
  "hostname": "something_else",
  "name": "something_else",
  "version": "6.2.4"
},
```

According to the document, it said that if I set `fields_under_root: true`, it will override the existing root field. But it does not seem to do so.

### Version

- Filebeat 6.2.4
- Logstash 6.2.4

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered you can override any of the module's prospector options by adding `prospector` to the module config. Any of the prospector options must be indented such that they become children of `prospector`. Your indentation of `fields_under_root` is slightly wrong.

```
- module: apache2
  access:
    enabled: false
  error:
    enabled: true
    prospector:
      fields:
        vhost: stackoverflow.com
      fields_under_root: true
```

However you cannot override `beat.name` by using `fields`. The only way to set this value is by adding `name: xxxx` to your filebeat.yml.

References:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.2/advanced-settings.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.2/configuration-general-options.html#_literal_name_literal